# VBA editor events

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some controls in MS Access form that change the system language to Turkish, Arabic and English and I want to change the system language to English when I go to VBA to write some code.

I have a code that change system language and want to know 
How to run this code automatically when I activate VBA editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the following code on start of your application, it would run automatically Test2, whenever you press Alt+F11.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnKey "%{F11}", "Test2"

End Sub


Public Sub Test2()

    Debug.Print "tested"

End Sub
```

I am not sure whether this is exactly what you want, but it is a work around to achieve it.

Edit:
Actually, here you may find plenty of useful stuff:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/468063-determine-language-user.html

E.g. With the Sub ShowLanguages you may built a function telling you which language are you using and if it is not English, you may switch to it, the way you do it in your answer. I would probably built something similar later.

```
Private Const LOCALE_ILANGUAGE As Long = &H1
Private Const LOCALE_SCOUNTRY As Long = &H6

Private Declare Function GetKeyboardLayout Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal dwLayout As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" _
    (ByVal Locale As Long, _
    ByVal LCType As Long, _
    ByVal lpLCData As String, _
    ByVal cchData As Long) As Long

Public Sub ShowLangauges()
    Dim hKeyboardID As Long
    Dim LCID As Long

    hKeyboardID = GetKeyboardLayout(0&)
    If hKeyboardID > 0 Then
        LCID = LoWord(hKeyboardID)
        Debug.Print GetUserLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE)
        Debug.Print GetUserLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_SCOUNTRY)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function LoWord(wParam As Long) As Integer
    If wParam And &H8000& Then
        LoWord = &H8000& Or (wParam And &H7FFF&)
    Else
        LoWord = wParam And &HFFFF&
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetUserLocaleInfo(ByVal dwLocaleID As Long, _
                                  ByVal dwLCType As Long) As String
    Dim sReturn As String
    Dim nSize As Long
    nSize = GetLocaleInfo(dwLocaleID, dwLCType, sReturn, Len(sReturn))
    If nSize > 0 Then
        sReturn = Space$(nSize)
        nSize = GetLocaleInfo(dwLocaleID, dwLCType, sReturn, Len(sReturn))
        If nSize > 0 Then
            GetUserLocaleInfo = Left$(sReturn, nSize - 1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thank You Vityata, but I don't use `ALT + F11` to activate VBA editor I use the mouse. but this answer is good workaround if there is no way to fire activate  event for VBA editor.

Comment: If you find another way, tag me in the answer :)

Comment: sure, and if i didn't find another way I will accept your answer, thank You again.

Comment: I post new answer that I use. it is not what I'm looking for but it is not bad.

Comment: Thank You for adding new information, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use Timer to check if VBA editor window is the active window every 0.5 Sec and if true I run my function that change the language to English and stop Timer:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
 Dim st As String
 On Error Resume Next
 st = VBE.ActiveWindow.Caption
 If Err = 0 Then
  ChLng 1033
  Me.TimerInterval = 0
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And I run Timer again when any control on my form change the language to non English language:

```
Private Sub cmbAR_GotFocus()
 ChLng 1025
 Me.TimerInterval = 500
End Sub

Private Sub cmbTR_GotFocus()
 ChLng 1055
 Me.TimerInterval = 500
End Sub
```

In Form design I manually add all needed events including Form Load event that run the Timer:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
 Me.TimerInterval = 500
End Sub
```

NOTE: `ChLng xxxx` is the function that change the language:

(Find your desired language at [BCP 47 Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a))

```
Private Declare Function ActivateKeyboardLayout Lib _
"user32.dll" (ByVal myLanguage As Long, Flag As Boolean) As Long

'define your desired keyboardlanguage    

Sub ChLng(lng As Long)
 ActivateKeyboardLayout lng, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. How does   ChLng 1033 look like?

Comment: @Vityata,I found it in the net but I don't remember from where .I edit the answer, thank You again.